# How I delete a row from csv file after I am down with it using python and numpy

Tags: python, csv, numpy

i have csv file that I am performing so function for each row in the file.

```
 csv = np.genfromtxt ('NSNDatabase.csv',  dtype='str', delimiter=",", skip_header=1)
```

once I am done using that row I want to delete the row from the csv file 
I tried this

```
 np.delete(csv, **NSN)
```

NSN is what I named each row. The above code does not work I tried without the asterics but yielded this error

> > invalid literal for int() with base 10

how can I delete the row from csv file after I am done with it.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know that

```
np.delete(csv, **NSN)
```

Make sure you understand what you are working with, including the function definition.  And when talking about problems show by example what you and what you get.

`csv` is not a file, but an array created by reading a file.  Changing that array isn't going to change the file.

Read the `delete` docs.  It returns a new array, leaving `csv` untouched.

I have no idea what your `NSN` is like.  It should be a list of row numbers.  `**NSN` syntax only works with dictionaries, and only if the keys match the keywords of the function ('obj', 'axis').

You should also show the shape of `csv`.  From the `genfromtxt` I can deduce it is a string dtype.